# how can i add Video thumbnails in listview in vb

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am writing a simple windows application to show the split the video through ffmpeg and show in a listview control . i am able to store the video in a folder . How can i show the Thumbnails in listview ?  Any suggestion ..

```
enter code here
ListView1.Items.Clear()
Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(SPath & "\" & FolderName & "\")
Dim aryFi As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.*")
Dim fi As IO.FileInfo
For Each fi In aryFi
''ListView1.Items.Add(fi.FullName)
''ListBox1.Items.Add(fi)
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new ImageList component and set your listview's ImageList property to the new ImageList. Here the ImageList is named ImageList1.
Then, modify your For loop:

```
For Each fi In aryFi
    Dim ico As Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fi.FullName)
    ImageList1.Images.Add(ico)
    ListView1.Items.Add(fi.FullName, ImageList1.Images.Count - 1)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(fi)
Next
```